# How to trace a word back to where it was declared across multiple files in vim?

Tags: vim

When reading through a person's code, I may be looking through a program that comprises 10+ files. I would like the ability to search for where an object/struct/type def have been declared.

Does vim allow you to do this kind of search? If so how?

Comment: Vim itself does usually not contain a vcs. Which vcs is involved and if there is one, the question relates probably to the vcs, not vim. (Version Control System)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CTRL-]` command to "Jump to the definition of the keyword under the cursor." (see `:h ctrl-]`).

For this to work, you will need to create a tags file, for example with a program like ctags. The manual has more on this, see `:h tag`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use `lvim` to grep a word across multiple files.

[From the documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim) :

> to search for the words "house" or "home" in all .txt files in the
>   current directory, use:

```
:lvim /\<\(house\|home\)\>/gj *.txt
:lw
```

You can also integrate external programs, like `grep` or `findstr` into vim for faster searching, but those will depend on your OS: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim#Using_external_programs_for_fast_searches